# Tutorial: How to use Zend i18n

Tags: internationalization, zend-framework3

I would like to use Zend Translation to translate my app into various languages. The problem I face is finding a tutorial that explains how to set it up clearly and without any ambiguity.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

In the language file I have:

[image]

And in my view I am calling:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('Skeleton Application') ?>
```

And I am expecting the output: "hello"

Instead the text: "Skeleton Application" is returned.

Now I assume I need to do some configuration to set this all up such as setting locale etc. However, I can not find any documentation on this or what to do and where...

In Application.Config.php the following modules are included:

```
Zend\I18n',
'Zend\Mvc\I18n',
```

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything setup right. Both modules are indeed required as one is the actual translator, and the other one is the integration in Zend MVC (view helpers and all).

In terms of what's not working, it is not ZF related, but rather po/mo related. The translation file you are editing is the `.po` file, the human readable format, which then needs to be compiled into a `.mo` file, a binary that is going to be used by your system.

In your specific case, you are missing the compilation to binary step, hence the value not changing (as the `.mo` file has not changed).

You can either use a command line tool for that compilation, or use a tool such as poeditor on you machine to edit your translation files.

Comment: Yes thank you - I downloaded PoEditor and all works well.